# Add Deducted Amount To Balance

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So I'm trying to add the amount deducted into the database should the transaction fail but it's not working

```
function addBalance($userId, $amount){

    $results = DB::update("
        UPDATE users 
        SET balance = balance + :amount
        WHERE id =:user_id",
        [
            "user_id"=> $userId,
            "amount"=> $amount,

        ]);
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" is completely useless to us. Please describe what's not working. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happened? What error messages are you getting? Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "it's not working" means what?

Comment: you should read up in the manual https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-statements

Comment: I do not get an error message, what I expect is that the subtracted amount is added to the balance please

Comment: _"The update method returns the number of affected rows."_ What is the value of `$results`?

Comment: it's giving negative numbers

Comment: it returns the amount I was charged on the transaction in negative. Eg: $5.00 charge whiles balance is $20 will return -$5.00